# React select not showing options after first selection

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have a dropdown made with react-select, with multiple options that i get from an api. The code is working, when clicked the dropdown show the options, but when I select one option it stop showing the other ones. I don't what could it be since the isMulti prop is on.

Here is the code:

```
export const DropDown = ({ itemsOption, placeholder }) => {
  const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);

  const loadOptions = (op) => {
    api.get(`${op}`).then(({ data }) => {
      setOptions(
        data.map((item) => {
          return {
            key: item.code,
            label: item.name_ptbr,
          };
        })
      );
    });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    loadOptions(itemsOption);
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <DropStyled>
        <Select
          isMulti
          options={options}
          name={placeholder}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          closeMenuOnSelect={false}
        />
      </DropStyled>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: I have the same problem here. Let me know if you found the solution!

Answer (score -1):

An option needs a `value` property for react-select to map the data to its options.

So when mapping over the fetched data, add `value` along with `label` and `key`.

```
 return {
            key: item.code,
            label: item.name_ptbr,
            value: item.name_ptbr,
        };
```